# Cannot Zoom Android Map fragment to the current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

This is not the first question im posting regarding this matter in Stack Overflow. I really need help to zoom my map fragment to the current location. Please don't think I'm not trying anything. I tried a lot.

I need to zoom my map to the current location and **no matter how hard I tried map zoom to another location not my current location. Cannot even possibly think what is happening here**.

Here is my `GoogleMapsFragment.java`

```
public class GoogleMapsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    View rootView;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng latlng;

    public GoogleMapsFragment()
    {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(!isGooglePlayServiceAvailable())
        {
           return null;
        }

        if(rootView != null)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)rootView.getParent();
            if(parent != null)
            {
                parent.removeView(rootView);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_maps, container, false);
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            if (mapFragment != null)
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable()
    {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
        if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Zoom to the current location
    public Location getMyLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null)
        {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())) // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5), 5000, null);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

I think I've dome a small mistake and it zooms to another location and it is not even close to my country.

Here is the image of my zooming location.

[image: Screen Shot of the Map]

Someone please tell me how to zoom my map fragment to the current location.

Any kind of help may appreciated. :)

~ Edit for Gaurav ~

Added getMyLocation() inside onMapReady()

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        getMyLocation();

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5), 5000, null);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);


    }
```

~ Edited full code ~

```
public class GoogleMapsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    View rootView;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng latlng;

    public GoogleMapsFragment()
    {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(!isGooglePlayServiceAvailable())
        {
           return null;
        }

        if(rootView != null)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)rootView.getParent();
            if(parent != null)
            {
                parent.removeView(rootView);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_maps, container, false);
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            if (mapFragment != null)
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable()
    {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
        if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Zoom to the current location
    public Location getMyLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null)
        {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())) // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        Location myLocation =  getMyLocation();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                latLng
                , 15));

    }

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 1000;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 900;

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

~ Error Log ~

```
06-16 11:23:28.180    6647-6647/com.myayubo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myayubo, PID: 6647
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myayubo.GoogleMapsFragment.onMapReady(GoogleMapsFragment.java:151)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzl$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.v$a$a.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:82)
            at maps.ei.bu$6.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

       Location myLocation =  getMyLocation();

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getlatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
 map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                latLng
                , 15));
}
```

and

```
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 1000;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 900;
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

       mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
                mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
                mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }
```

this will call onLocationChanged();

Comment: Nothing happened. :(

Comment: Yeah! `getMyLocation()`  dioesn't even calling. Zooming part is happening `onMapReady()` I don't know what to do.

Comment: call `getMyLocation()` from `onMapReady()`

Comment: Please look at the edited part. Nothing happened. :( Did u looked at the whole code? I cannot see a solution. :(

Comment: it actually its getting LastKnow location not current location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114804/discussion-between-quality-products-and-gaurav).

Comment: I think its zooming to the I think its zooming to the equator :(

Comment: because its not getting current location ,
this may works if you open google maps app get current location , close it and open your this app.

but for correct code 
check updated ans

Comment: I added your code and Application crashes. Can u kindly check the edited full code and my crash log in my question? :(

Comment: which line is at com.myayubo.GoogleMapsFragment.onMapReady(GoogleMapsFragment.java:151)

Comment: `LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());`

Comment: I cannot resolve `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` and I cast 3 parameters and now it is `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);' and this gives another error csalling, `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myayubo.GoogleMapsFragment cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
            at com.myayubo.GoogleMapsFragment.onConnected(GoogleMapsFragment.java:179)`

Comment: I'm very sry to disturb you like this. I'm knid of new to Andrdoid :(

Comment: ok then please try to refer this tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-tracker-with-google-maps/

Comment: Thanks. I'll refer. :)

Comment: Code is working for later versions but not for Marshmillow. anwy thanks for the help. :)

Comment: It will work for Marshmallow after adding **run time permission check**

Comment: God! i did off my location. Thats why it is not working. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling onLocationChanged(), from within getMyLocation()

Comment: Tried. no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check whether you are receiving location coordinates values or not, if receiving try using this one

```
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
```

This could be useful for you.